# What's the difference between Full-width grids and Centered grids in material design?

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I read [Adaptive UI - Full-width vs Centered](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/adaptive-ui.html#adaptive-ui-grid).

I'm not sure what's the difference between them.

Could someone explain it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use centered grid, it takes fixed width (not all space on the screen) and on smaller screen it adapts ( like in responsive design in Web). When you use Full-width grid, it takes all screen space and do not adapts blocks inside (it do not changes their positions).
Take a little more attention to gif in the Full-width vs Centered block.

Comment: Sorry. Could I also ask what "breakpoint" exactly means in the description ? Thank you.

Comment: Breakpoint is like a "Size block". Main breakpoints is 480, 600, 840, 960, 1280, 1440, and 1600dp. Table with breakpoints just helping you, how many columns in the grid should be in each screen. For example, screen sizes from 0 to 480 must have only 4 columns (not more), 600 to 720 only 8 columns, 840 and more must have 12 columns

Comment: It says "Desktop breakpoints are 16dp below the listed values to accommodate variations in browser chrome." Does "16dp" here refer to "the listed values (the breakpoint column in the table) minus 16" ?

Comment: Does "column" in this page of guidelines refer to the spaces between the blue lines in those animations, and "grid" refer to these blue lines ?

Comment: Yes. And as result, 12-column grid system is very simple and useful.

Comment: Are both two above questions ( It says "Desktop breakpoints ... , Does "comlumn" ... ) correct ?

Comment: What do you mean? I do not understand ;D

Comment: I mean that your yes refer to both two questions I ask (It says "Desktop breakpoints" … , Does "column" in this page … ) are correct?

Comment: Oh, sorry, "Yes" was answer only for last question (Doest "column")

Comment: Could I also ask that It says "Desktop breakpoints are 16dp below the listed values to accommodate variations in browser chrome." Does "16dp" here refer to "the listed values (the breakpoint column in the table) minus 16" ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, i think so. If breakpoint is 1024, in practice, it starts from (1024-16) 1008dp. If 1280, in practice it starts from (1280-16) 1264dp. Also, i think it because of scroll element in browsers. When you have scroll (in right side of your browser, when your web-page is long), it takes aroun 10-20px from your window, and real size of your window is "window real size - scroll width".